# Script not executing properly when using /bin/sh

Tags: shell, redhat, ps

My script doesnt function properly when I execute using just sh, it used to function fine before until today. Even in cronjob it used to execute without a problem.

```
/bin/sh process_check.sh
```

But it seems to execute fine when I execute using the following way

```
./process_check.sh
```

Script (checks if a process is running, executes the process if it's not running)

```
#/bin/sh
     $service=xxx

    if (( $(/bin/ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 1 ))
      then
         true
      else
         echo "$service is not running!!!"
         /usr/sbin/xxx
      fi
```

Also, any ways to make this much more efficient? I have a compiled program that I am trying to ensure is always running.

Comment: Instead of `if (( $(/bin/ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 1 )); then` try the much simpler: `if /bin/ps -ef | grep -q $service; then`

Comment: @WilliamPursell There is a problem with that.  Even if `$service` is not running, the process `grep -q $service` may be included in the `ps` output .  That is why the OP's code asked for `>1` (that is two or more). processes matching `$service`.

Comment: You want to execute it with Bourne Shell (`sh`), but you are using `((....))` and `$(....)` which are not defined in Bourne. Of course if on your system, sh is linked to bash, this error won't be evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is this line:

```
$service=xxx
```

This likely should be:

```
service=xxx
```

Also, the following is inherently unreliable:

```
(( $(/bin/ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 1 ))
```

The number of processes found this way in a multitasking system depends on accidents of timing.  A more reliable approach is to use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep "$service"
```

This will list PIDs for `$service` without the possibility of matching the `grep` process.

Because `pgrep` sets a useful return code all by itself, there is no need for math test.  Thus, replace:

```
if (( $(/bin/ps -ef | grep $service | wc -l) > 1 ))
```

With:

```
if pgrep -q "$service"
```

where `-q` tells `pgrep` to just set the exit code without listing the PIDs to stdout.

If your `pgrep` does not support the `-q` option, then use:

```
if pgrep "$service" >/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you! -q doesnt seem to work for me, can I just use pgrep "service"? i'm using SH4.1

Comment: @LeRay OK.  I updated the answer with what to do if your `pgrep` doesn't support `-q`.  (Any moderately recent linux should support `pgrep -q`.  If your OS does not have `pgrep` at all, let me know and we can discuss alternatives.)

Answer (score 2):

In the first line of the script, you used #/bin/sh instead of #!/bin/sh. When you use ./process_check.sh it uses /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh.